# What command returns the number of clusters in dbscan as a value?

Tags: r, command, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I need to a command, similar to `length()`, to find the number of clusters created in a dbscan.

Suppose I have perform a dbscan on this data set

```
set.seed(665544)
n <- 600
x <- cbind(runif(10, 0, 10)+rnorm(n, sd=0.2), runif(10, 0, 10)+rnorm(n,sd=0.2))
ds<- dbscan(x,.2,showplot=1)
```

I can use the command ds to view the number of clusters

```
ds
```

Is there a command that I can type and a value for the number of clusters is returned? i.e. I type a command and the value 12 is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look on the structure of object `ds` you will see that there are variable `cluster` containing cluster number for each observation. `0` in variable `cluster` is used to code noise observations (see help file of `dbscan()`).

```
 str(ds)
List of 4
 $ cluster: num [1:600] 1 2 3 4 5 10 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ eps    : num 0.2
 $ MinPts : num 5
 $ isseed : logi [1:600] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "dbscan"
```

To find the number of clusters you can look on maximal value of that variable. Results is 11.

```
 max(ds$cluster)
[1] 11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command

```
length(table(ds$cluster))-1
```

The -1 will remove the 0 cluster

Comment: But this will count also 0 class that is used for observations that don't belong to clusters

Comment: ok, i didn't know that the 0 cluster was not a real cluster.  thanks